# After typing 'info bash', how do I exit the documentation?

Tags: bash, terminal, operating-systems, documentation, navigation

I tried to use the terminal. I typed "help" and was happy to see a list of commands appear on the screen, among which "use 'info bash' to find out more about the shell in general".
So I typed 'info bash', and these words appeared :

```
File: ada-mode, Node: GNU Free Documentation License, Next: Index, Prev: Comment Handling, Up: Top
```

followed by various text paragraphs.

It looks like when I press the spacebar, I can jump to the next page of text. I cannot find how to exit this "application". How should I do ?

What is the name of this application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the GNU info system for documentation. To exit, hit <kbd>q</kbd>. To learn about it, enter `info info`

Comment: As a general rule, text viewers in Unix (anything that is `less` or looks like `less`) are exited with `q`. So remember this key also for `man` and similar commands.